# issue with Calling user control public functions from main form in ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, webusercontrol

I created a user control in ASP.net C# with a Dropdownlist in it (called LookupGrid below). Now in the main form , I want to set the data source for the Combobox, but I am getting NullExceptions when on the line that sets the datasource for the combobox

Code in the main web form :

```
LookupGrid droplist = new LookupGrid();
droplist.ID = field.Name;
RecordSet lookupvalues = inRecs.ServiceClient.WebServiceClient.GetInstance().GetLookup("CurrentNRS_Admit", Convert.ToInt64(Session["UserID"].ToString()), field);
droplist.SetData(lookupvalues.ToDataSet());
```

In the user control :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
public void SetData(DataSet dTLookupValues)
{
    DropDownList1.DataSource = dTLookupValues.Tables[0];
}
```

I am getting error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

On this line:

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = dTLookupValues.Tables[0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create property and set the data table from the public method. in page load you can bind the data

```
public DataTable MyData { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList1.DataSource =MyData  ;
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
}

public void SetData(DataSet dTLookupValues)
{
    MyData  = dTLookupValues.Tables[0];
}
```

in your main page

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var control = (LookupGrid )LoadControl("~/LookupGrid.ascx");
        control.SetData(lookupvalues.ToDataSet());
        Panel1.Controls.Add(control); //add control to your page or panel
    }
```

Comment: Thanks , can you explain why is that?

Comment: read about asp.net page life cycle. server controls in the tree are created and initialized on page load, to set a property value of control, you need to have initialized control

Comment: Are you sure that's the only thing i need to do to initialize? Now I get the error on this line :   DropDownList1.DataSource =MyData  ;